# How to I solve a Visual Studio Fatal Error during debugging involving Desktop CLR, CoreCLR and recommending Managed Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, coreclr

I'm afraid the error is so baffling to me I didn't even know how to word the question! I'm writing a plugin that's a class library for a Third Party Application (call it 'ApplicationX'). I had this successfully set up in a debug environment where it would build to ApplicationX's Plugin folder with the .pdb file and then the VS debug would start ApplicationX, thus enabling me to debug the plugin/class library code. This was working fine until I had a System Drive crash >.< (my first ever + ouch!).

Here's the debug setup:

[image]

I've just come back to it. I couldn't tell you all the changes, but I'm on VS2022 now as opposed to 2019. Now when I run it (the source code and ApplicationX is still much the same), I get this really weird error:

[image]

I've read through all the SO articles I could find and tried the suggesitons therein, but nothings worked. Firstly, I just can't understand the error. Secondly, Are there any suggestions on what to do. Here's what I've tried:

- Installing .net Core 3.1 and 6 (full + desktop versions)
- In options>debugging>general, checked "automatically close the console when debugging stops"
- Some other stuff that I can't remember right now!

Be grateful of any help as this has brought my dev to a grinding halt!

Comment: Do you know which runtime you actually use? .NET3.1, .NET6.0 or .NET Framework? The error message indicates you've got some kind of mess there.

Comment: Yeah - I solved it in the end. 'ApplicationX' turned out to have been built in a .net Core version. So it was about a mismatch there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I got in touch with the author of 'ApplicationX' He confirmed that he'd migrated it to .net Core. So that was the issue. I haven't got the solution in terms of solving it from that perspective, as I switched to the .net Framework version of ApplicationX instead! Non-the-less, the error's a bit clearer.